# How to show No Data available on load function of c3 JS chart

Tags: d3.js, c3.js

I am making a chart with data initially, but again if data is not available in the chart on load function it is not showing no data available string.

```js
var chart = c3.generate({
 bindto: '#chart1',   
 data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', -30, 200, 200, 400, -150, 250],
            ['data2', 130, 100, -100, 200, -150, 50]
        ],
        type: 'bar',
        groups: [
            ['data1', 'data2']
        ],
        empty: { label: { text: "No Data Available" }   }
    },
    grid: {
        y: {
            lines: [{value:0}]
        }
    }
});


setTimeout(function () {

    chart.load({
        columns: [
        
        
        ],
        empty: { label: { text: "No Data Available" }   }
    });
    chart.flush();
}, 1500);
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/masayuki0812/c3/master/c3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/masayuki0812/c3/master/c3.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart1"></div>
```

How to show no Data available on load function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For loading new data you need to unload the old data by their ids:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  chart.load({
    columns: [],
    unload: ['data1', 'data2']//here data1, data2 are your old data ids
  });

chart.flush();
}, 1500);
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/hCGynHDXQde6Yu3jpbTA?p=preview)

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks :)